# Cargo fails to download nom v0.5.0

Tags: dependencies, rust, rust-cargo, nom

I'm trying to use [Nom](https://github.com/Geal/nom) but getting the following error when running `cargo build --verbose`:

```
Unable to get packages from source

Caused by:
  Failed to unpack package `nom v0.5.0`

Caused by:
  The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
 (os error 123)
```

My `Cargo.toml` looks like this:

```
[package]
name = "hello_world"
version = "0.1.0"
authors = ["bob"]
[dependencies]
nom = "~0.5.0"
```

How do I fix this? `cargo update` does not help. I'm using cargo 0.5.0-nightly (833b947 2015-09-13) installed as part of the Rust 1.4 release (Windows 7, x64).

Comment: For what it is worth, I see the same problem with Rust 1.4 and a Windows 7 / x86 virtual machine. What is strange is that the crate does appear to be expanded and the source files available (`\Users\myuser\.cargo\registry\src\...`).

Comment: Other packages download correctly? Can you test a different version of `nom`?

Comment: 0.4.0 worked fine! Interesting..

Comment: There's now an [issue filed about this](https://github.com/rust-lang/cargo/issues/2102).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last beta version (1.0.0-beta2, and the future stable release) should fix that.